# OpenLayers 6 on Rails target.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, turbolinks, openlayers-6

i start from the scratch to build a Rails 6 Application with Openlayers 6.1.1. with Webpacker and Turbolinks. Many things are working fine, also with turbolinks. 
But one thing will not work fine: Openlayers. 
I add openlayers with yarn an it is basically working. So i can create a map as i expected, but i am not able to add a VectorLayer. If i do this i will get a console message with :

```
 target.addEventListener is not a function
```

I mean i am importing all required libs. In my application.js

```
require("@openlayers/pepjs")
require("ol")
```

In my map.js

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import MVT from 'ol/format/MVT';
import View from 'ol/View';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import Circle from 'ol/geom/Circle';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
//import { Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style } from 'ol/style';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
```

And my map object:

```
var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({
        url: 'v1/track/journey',
        format: new GeoJSON()
    }),
});


var OSMMap = new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM({
        attributions: [
            '(c) OpenStreetMap'
        ],
        opaque: false,
        url: 'http://10.232.200.17/tiles/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    })
});

// OL Test
var map = new Map({
    layers: [
        OSMMapHLC1,
        VectorLayer
    ],

    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    })
});
```

- I tried it without turbolinks
- I added pepjs
- I added jquery manually
- I tried Leaflet. Result VectorLayers an Realtime Plugin working fine.

Hint. I have to use Openlayers not Leaflet.

Many thanks to everyone who can help.

> > > > > [Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuP9r.png)

Regards Marco

Comment: Do you have the target map element in the DOM, i.e. `<div id="map"></div>`?

Comment: Yes, the map is working until I put a vector layer on it

Comment: Please add stack trace of `target.addEventListener is not a function` error. then we could find out what's not working.

Comment: Stack trace added to my question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you so much for your answer. i thinks this was a copy-paste failure from my side. I had try so many things that my code was messed up. So i start from the scratch an now it is working, So i will show my code here:

It is mandatory to put all imports outside the turbolinks, everything else should be inside the turbolinks load() function:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import Circle from 'ol/geom/Circle';
import { Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import { OSM, Vector as VectorSource } from 'ol/source';
import { Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style } from 'ol/style';
//import { toPng } from 'html-to-image';



$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {


    var exportOptions = {
        filter: function(element) {
            return element.className ? element.className.indexOf('ol-control') === -1 : true;
        }
    };

    document.getElementById('export-png').addEventListener('click', function() {
        map.once('rendercomplete', function() {
            toPng(map.getTargetElement(), exportOptions)
                .then(function(dataURL) {
                    var link = document.getElementById('image-download');
                    link.href = dataURL;
                    link.click();
                });
        });
        map.renderSync();
    });

    var image = new CircleStyle({
        radius: 5,
        fill: null,
        stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'red', width: 1 })
    });

    var styles = {
        'Point': new Style({
            image: image
        }),
        'LineString': new Style({
            stroke: new Stroke({
                color: 'green',
                width: 1
            })
        }),
        'MultiLineString': new Style({
            stroke: new Stroke({
                color: 'green',
                width: 1
            })
        }),
        'MultiPoint': new Style({
            image: image
        }),
        'MultiPolygon': new Style({
            stroke: new Stroke({
                color: 'yellow',
                width: 1
            }),
            fill: new Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.1)'
            })
        }),
        'Polygon': new Style({
            stroke: new Stroke({
                color: 'blue',
                lineDash: [4],
                width: 3
            }),
            fill: new Fill({
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
            })
        }),
        'GeometryCollection': new Style({
            stroke: new Stroke({
                color: 'magenta',
                width: 2
            }),
            fill: new Fill({
                color: 'magenta'
            }),
            image: new CircleStyle({
                radius: 10,
                fill: null,
                stroke: new Stroke({
                    color: 'magenta'
                })
            })
        }),
        'Circle': new Style({
            stroke: new Stroke({
                color: 'red',
                width: 2
            }),
            fill: new Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)'
            })
        })
    };

    var styleFunction = function(feature) {
        return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
    };



    var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
            format: new GeoJSON(),
            url: 'v1/track?journey=#####'
        }),
        style: styleFunction
    });



    var map = new Map({
        layers: [
            new TileLayer({
                source: new OSM()
            }),
            vectorLayer
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2
        })
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try to replace this on your code:

```
var map = new Map({
layers: [
    OSMMap,
    vectorLayer
],
```